# Is is possible to make a secure JS script or function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security

Is it possible to have a secure piece of Javascript code in a web application?  By *secure* I mean that we can do things like query the server for permissions, and do operations that cannot be altered by the client?

Example:

```
    var flag = 0;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/check_permission_script.php",
        success: function(data){
            flag = parseInt(data);
        }
    });

    if (flag != 1){
        display_normal_content();
    }else{
        display_secure_content();
    }
```

Here I want to make a query to the server to check if the user has permission to see the secure content.  If they have the permissions, then we use `display_secure_content()` to show them the secure content, if not, we use `display_normal_content()` to display normal content.  The problem is, that via a debugging terminal, it is easy to set the `flag` variable == 1 on the client computer, or just call the `display_secure_content()` function directly.

My motivation for doing things this way is to have nice web app that uses ajax to get new content, without having to reload the page.  I like this instead of having to reload the page.

So the question is, can we have JS scripts that are secure against client manipulation?  Or is this simply impossible by the nature of the web infrastructure?

Thanks!!

Comment: Unless `display_secure_content()` makes another ajax call, your secure content will be visible in the source of the page. Why don't you just get the right content from the server with the initial ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no - not with JavaScript alone. JavaScript executes on the client-side, so anything you put in it is accessible and by extension modifiable by the client.

Several tools exist to help with "security through obscurity" such as obfuscating the code, but this will not help you for your end goal.

What could help, given your current setup, is through Ajax you contact a server-side PHP page that handles all security/validation and returns what content to display. Doing this, the client-facing JavaScript only has the ability to "request", not to validate or choose what to display.

Answer (score 2):

By the very nature of JavaScript, this is not possible.

Anything you want to not be seen by the client cannot be sent to the client at all.  All authentication/authorization should happen server-side.

You can still use AJAX for loading data in your interface, but make sure the checks are in place server-side to keep sensitive data from leaking out.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the session id against your internal database and return a secure public/private key encrypted token which contains a key for decrypting a blob of data. Then use this as a parameter of the javascript function, which uses this returned key to decrypt the blob.

This solution does not require reloading the page, and whilst it works in theory, you would have to return the page with the secure content encrypted with a different key each time. I wouldn't recommend actually trying this.

Answer (score 1):

The server should know what the user can and can not see. If the flag is changed on the client, the server should not trust it, it should do a validation when it gets the request. Security 101 stuff

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client side scripting language. It's meant to be this way.

If you need a secure script, use PHP.

Comment: I said PHP because question is tagged with php ;)